# How to compile Python + Electron JS into desktop app (exe)

Tags: python, compilation, electron, exe

I created a desktop application using **python as the backend** and **Electron JS integrated with Node JS as the front end**.

The image below is the file tree for my project.

[image]

I was able to link up both the python with Electron JS using the `renderer.js` file and my app functions as expected.

But my question is, how should I compile this **Python + Electron JS** app into an `exe`. I am aware that **`pyinstaller`** can be used to compile python files to `exe`. Please let me know how to compile this `python + electron JS` app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found some material about how to create executable from python, can be potentially helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project but it's not answering the node part, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the thread regarding python compilation. Let me know if you find out any potentially helpful resource regarding my question.

Comment: HTML+CSS+JavaScript on the fronted + Python on the backend is on [Tauri](https://tauri.studio/en/docs/about/intro/) roadmap. For now PyQt is a much better solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So after a bit of research, I was able to find out the solution myself.

## **Step 1: Compile the python file to an `exe`**

First, you need to convert the `python` file to a single `exe` using `pyinstaller`. The command is

```
pyinstaller --onefile engine.py
```

You will find `engine.exe` inside the `dist` folder. Copy the `exe` to the main directory where you have the `renderer.js`. Delete all the other python related folders.

## Step 2: Making modifications to the `renderer.js` file

Initially, I had a `renderer.js` file with the following code. ***Note:*** The following code was there to run my python script using `sys.argv` for the input and get the output using `stdout`.

```js
function sendToPython() {
    var python = require("child_process").spawn("python", [
        "./py/engine.py",
        input.value,
    ]);

    python.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    // Do some process here
    });

    python.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    python.on("close", (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
}
```

But now that we have generated the `exe` file, we need to make some modifications to get this working. We need to simply change the line.

```
var python = require("child_process").spawn("python", ["./py/engine.py", input.value]);
```

Following is the amended version of the line.

```
var python = require("child_process").execFile("engine.exe", [input.value]);
```

In short, what this does is that, it executes our `engine.exe` with command line arguments without spawning a python shell.

## Step 3: Using `electron-packager` to package our app

Open a terminal in your project folder and run the following commands (one after the other) to install `electron-packager` globally using `npm`.

```
npm install --save-dev electron
npm install electron-packager -g
```

Once that is installed, we can use the following command to package our app.

```
electron-packager . pythonElectronApp --arch=x64 --asar
```

***Note:*** `pythonElectronApp` is the name of the project (you can name it according to your wish), `--arch=x64` means 64-bit architecture.

`--asar` packages your project in a way that it stops a most people from viewing your source code. Anyways, almost all can see the source by inspecting the `asar` file that Electron dumps out. You can try methods like code obfuscation to slow down a attacker from reverse engineering.

***Useful resource regarding code obfuscation*** - [How to perform obfuscation of source code and protect source in electron js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103656/how-to-perform-obfuscation-of-source-code-and-protect-source-in-electron-js)

***Similar issue reported in github*** - https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/issues/152

## Step 4: Placing our `engine.exe` at the correct directory

Copy the `engine.exe` that we created earlier and paste it inside the folder where your electron app was created. In my case it is, `pythonElectronApp-win32-x64`

Now you can open up your fully functional `python+electron` app. In my case the name is `pythonElectronApp.exe`

## Step 5: Create a main installer file `.msi`

As you saw earlier in the previous image, there are a lot dependencies and folders. To create one standalone installer like a `.msi` for windows, you can use a software like [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to do it for you.

Comment: this is very limited solution cuz you can only spawn an exe file with  no communication made, idk how this would work with big projects.

Comment: Please suggest another solution if you have a better method of implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you really want.  If you just want a web front end for python then you can skip Electron all together and use [CEF Python](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython).  [Here's another thread about compiling python exes with CEF Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668568/how-to-compile-cefpython-to-exe).  [And here's the PyInstaller example from the CEF Python repo.](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/pyinstaller/README-pyinstaller.md)